# Matching regex for optional values

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract some information from web server log and it's not very structured so I run into troubles, I'm trying to match :

Example 1 :

```
2011-11-29 11:30:23,685 DEBUG [my.fully.qualified.package.Service] Added Action Item: M= 2  Success
```

Example 2 :

```
2011-11-29 11:30:23,685 DEBUG [my.fully.qualified.package.Service] Added Action Item: M=10  Success
```

This regex works for example 1 :

```
(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)\s[\d|:]+,\d+\s([A-Z]+)\s\[(.+)\]\s.+:\sM=\s(\d).+
```

Where first group is the date, second is log level, third is class name and third one is the value of `M`.

You may have noticed that in example 1, after M= there is a space before digit and in the other example there is not that's why this regex is not working.

I did try something like `M=[\s|d]+` but I get some more characters matched that I asked for, anyone have suggestion how to match both of these examples with one regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `M=\s*(\d+)` that will allow zero or more whitespace immediately after the `=`, but not any whitespace after the digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
M=\s?(\d).+
```

Allows for an optional whitespace after the `=`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have some typo mistake,
it should be

`M=[\s|\d]+`